# Dask read_sql_table created an additional column

Tags: dask

I used this to create a dask DataFrame based on sql

```
dd_ticks = dd.read_sql_table("ticks",sql_uri,index_col="time")
    symbol  price   volume  time__1
time                
2000-01-01 00:00:00     SYMBOL  16.0    100     2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:01     SYMBOL  23.0    100     2000-01-01 00:00:01
2000-01-01 00:00:02     SYMBOL  20.0    100     2000-01-01 00:00:02
2000-01-01 00:00:03     SYMBOL  10.0    800     2000-01-01 00:00:03
2000-01-01 00:00:04     SYMBOL  7.0     600     2000-01-01 00:00:04
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2022-01-01 00:05:56     SYMBOL  18.0    200     2022-01-01 00:05:56
2022-01-01 00:05:57     SYMBOL  25.0    300     2022-01-01 00:05:57
2022-01-01 00:05:58     SYMBOL  6.0     600     2022-01-01 00:05:58
2022-01-01 00:05:59     SYMBOL  8.0     800     2022-01-01 00:05:59
2022-01-01 00:06:00     SYMBOL  30.0    500     2022-01-01 00:06:00
```

However, I realized, it created one more column called "time__1", is it really necessary? Could I drop it without negative impact? (what's the right way to drop it? within dd.read_sql_table?)

Comment: I believe this is related to sqlalchemy 1.4, https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7436

Comment: i see. thanks! i just keep it as is, probably nothing too bad for one more column...